# Coloring individual parts in a brush

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, gradient, brush

How do I colour each individual ribbon like the finished preview for these brushes?

[From DeviantArt:

[image: Example]](http://rozairo.deviantart.com/gallery/8543819#/d1s7dgn)

Answer (score 2):

The very basic steps here are:

make a new square document.

make a new layer

create a rectangular selection at center of document such that the width is 100% of document, it's height is about 30%.

pick the gradient tool and choose any gradient (pick a preset for now, since this an example)

fill the selection with the gradient. make the grade top to bottom.

deselect.

choose edit->transform-> warp

grab one of the bottom center gadgets and pull it up above the top gadgets.

The example you give also has lines and linear decoration layered on top of the gradient. You would do all the decoration before the warp procedure.

Comment: What's the real need for the warp though, the shape already exists as a brush - just want to add colour to it..

Comment: What you wanted wasn't entirely clear from your question, but now you know how to make your own from the ground up. If you want to replace the blue, use the selective color tool with a wide threshold to isolate the color and then modify it with the hue and saturation tool

Answer (score 0):

Photoshop Brushes do not contain any color information. There's a Brush Dynamic option for `Hue Shift` which will create a rather random color change. However there is no way to have a *brush* which contains color information for a gradient.

You'll have to think of another way.